# Why is there only error bars on some of the bars in barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Can anyone tell me why I only get errorbars on the total of each group, on not within each group?
Here's my code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = faceEmotion, y = correctPerc, colour = condition)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Emotions", y = "% correct")+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=condition), stat='summary', fun = mean, width = 0.5, position = 'dodge') +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", color = 'black', width = 0.1) +
  ggtitle("Perceived emotions and % correct")
```

And my plot looks like this.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: You have to make use of the group aes, i.e. add `group = condition`.

Comment: Oh yes of course. Thank you @stefan!

Comment: If that didn't work out, the next thing to try is adding `position = position_dodge(width = 0.4)` or something to the `stat_summary()` layer.